# Shiv'a Veshiv'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seventy-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

177 days in a typical six (Jewish) month period. Hence, 177 days from *Pesach* until (and excluding) *Sukos*, and, in some non-leap years, from *Sukos* until (and excluding) *Pesach*.

Answer (score 4):

There are 177 words in Hashem's instructions to Noach about building the Ark and what to put in it (Gen. 6:13-16, 18-21, and 7:1-4). This is also the gematria of the words מבול מים (a flood of water) plus the seven letters and two words of this phrase.

(From [Otzar Chaim, by R' Yeshuah Halevi of Lisbon](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38279&pgnum=19). I suppose he omits 6:17 because it's Hashem's description of the flood that He is going to bring (i.e., this isn't something for Noach to do); but in that case I'm not sure why he counts 6:13, which is also Hashem saying that he's fed up with the behavior of humanity and plans to do something about it.)

Answer (score 1):

(Terrible answer, but I've been unable as of yet to find anything else.)

177 is the total of the number (86) of years *Avraham* lived until *Yishmael* was born and the number (91) of years *Yaakov* lived until *Yosef* was born.

Comment: Well, this could be good for our muscles because ... I don't think we've had such a big stretch yet!

Comment: You could always keep this in mind for when we get to 237, and add Yitzchak...

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of 177 Jewish families residing in Belchatow's synagogue district with the right to vote for the Kahal. It is based on the list of community members who paid their contribution to the Kahal in 1891.

http://www.shtetlinks.jewishgen.org/belchatow/synagogue_name_list.htm